# The problem of displaying the welcome page more than once for the device

Tags: swift

in Swift UIKit

I have a welcome view Controller page at the beginning of the application

When you click on start now, the application pages will open

I have a problem that every time a user logs in, he will see this page every time

I use the app to view data from the API

Without the need to log in, the application is open to anyone

How do I make it appear once for each device?

[image]

Comment: Save the startup status with `UserDefaults`, `NSKeyedArchiver`, SQLite or whatever you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UserDefaults class allows you to store basic data types persistently without the hassle of databases or files. This is a perfect use case. Once the user completes the welcome process:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(true, forKey: "introduced")
```

When the app launches again, you can check whether "introduced" was found in UserDefaults, and if so, the boolean value:

```
isIntroduced = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "introduced") as? Bool ?? false
```

(above defaults to `false` if the key was not found)

You can then opt to only show the welcome page if the value is true.